# Parse "X years and Y weeks ago" alike strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, datetime

Is there a generic parser to parse "... ago" strings and turn them into DateTime objects?

Possible sentences are:

- 1 year|@count years (and 1 week|@count weeks) ago
- 1 week|@count weeks (and 1 day|@count days) ago
- 1 day|@count days (and 1 hour|@count hours) ago
- 1 hour|@count hours ago (and 1 min|@count min) ago
- 1 min|@count min ago (and 1 sec|@count sec) ago
- 1 sec|@count sec ago

So its either a combination of two (Foo and Bar ago) or only one (Foo ago). And it can be singular or plural.

Ruby's `DateTime::parse()` cannot handle this, nor can `DateTime::strptime()`.

I am hoping for a gem or a snippet somewhere that handles this.

Else I will have to create my own parser, in which case a pointer to how-to-create own DateTime Parsers would be very welcome.

Sidenote: For Future Reference: These are the timestrings generated by Drupals [Format Interval](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_interval/6)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Chronic](http://rubygems.org/gems/chronic) gem may be what you're looking for.

```
require 'chronic'
Chronic.parse "2 days ago"
# => 2011-06-14 14:13:59 -0700
```

Per @injekt (one of Chronic's maintainers), you can handle "1 year and 1 week ago" like this:

```
str = "one year and 1 week ago"
chunks = str.split('and')

Chronic.parse(chunks[1], :now => Chronic.parse(chunks[0] + 'ago'))
#=> 2010-06-09 14:29:37 -0700
```

Comment: (Chronic maintainer here) @dmarkow is correct, Chronic cannot handle things like '1 year and 1 week ago', it's usually quite easy to split those into segments and handle them separately, though. Feel free to open a feature request at http://github.com/mojombo/chronic though and I'll look into it!

Comment: Adding to this (I dont want to provide another answer to this question, this answer should be the accepted one). Checkout this snippet for handling multiple times: https://gist.github.com/61529720a993aaad30a3

Comment: @injekt Nice! I'll incorporate into my answer.

Comment: I have altered @injekt's answer so it can handle "foo and bar ago" as well as "foo ago" strings. https://gist.github.com/7920a8cfc62cf03ee179